# Downloaded file using CURL does not contain data

Tags: curl, command-line, download

I am trying to download a zip file through command prompt using the curl command. Here I am getting a zipped folder with no data in it

curl --user username:password -O https://artifactory.mas............../jenkins-ModuleBuilder-develop-100_BuildOutput.zip

Note : I am entering right username, password and URL. The zipped folder is created. also getting  this after executing the command -

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3024    0  3024    0     0   2371      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  2384

Need to understand what is incorrect